# Dynamically updating Dojox ListItem

Tags: dynamic, dojo, listitem

I have been working to update the contents of a particular list item via another pane.

I am able to successfully change the contents of the list item. The change is apparent when doing a `console.log()`, however, I cannot get the list item to update its' contents in the UI of the app.

`var LI = dijit.byId("widgetID");`
`LI.params.tagToChange = "a new value";`
`console.log(LI) // can confirm that the item has indeed been changed`

However, in the UI, the list item has not been updated. I cannot seem to find a refresh or re-render function that works. Calling `buildRendering()` throws an error. Does anyone know of a way to force refresh a list item or of some way to dynamically update the contents of a list item and have the UI update to reflect the change?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `widget.set('attr', value)` instead of setting properties directly